# How can I get hierarchical data without using CTE or loop?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have data in below format. I want to retrieve this data in hierarchical manner without using CTE or loop, just by writing T-SQL statements. How can I do that ?

```
ParentId    ChildId
1           2
1           3
1           4
2           5
2           6
3           7
5           8
8           9
```

Comment: You could do a self-join to get a 2-level hierarchy, but you would need to re-join for each level you need. Why can't you use a CTE?

Answer (score 0):

If you really can't use CTEs, you'll need to have join the table to itself several times like @DavidG commented, something like this:

```
select * 
from Table1 T1
left outer join Table1 T2 on T1.ChildId = T2.ParentId
left outer join Table1 T3 on T2.ChildId = T3.ParentId
left outer join Table1 T4 on T3.ChildId = T4.ParentId
left outer join Table1 T5 on T4.ChildId = T5.ParentId
where
not exists (select 1 from Table1 t where t.ChildId = T1.ParentId)
```

Which will return something like this:

```
ParentId     ChildId     ParentId     ChildId     ParentId     ChildId     ParentId     ChildId     ParentId     ChildId
1            2           2            5           5            8           8            9           NULL         NULL
1            2           2            6           NULL         NULL        NULL         NULL        NULL         NULL
1            3           3            7           NULL         NULL        NULL         NULL        NULL         NULL
1            4           NULL         NULL        NULL         NULL        NULL         NULL        NULL         NULL
```

Comment: Thanks DavidG, JamesZ.